# Почему в объекте языка JS не требуется клучевого слова function перед list(). Сейчас код работает

Tags: javascript

```
const logNumber = {
        message: "Номер > ",
        numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        list() {
          this.numbers.forEach(function (number) {
            console.log(this.message, number);
          });
        },
      };
      logNumber.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Эта возможность у языка появилась ещё в ECMAScript 6 (2015 год).

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#описание](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions#%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что JS защищается от подобного под капотом и создает объекту logNumber ключ с именем list и присваивает ему эту функцию.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).